# Select2 infinite scroll with no limited result

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using selct2 and I am loading some data with ajax. The result is not limited, but I have to make infinite scroll. Some ideas?

I have a json like this

```
{"len":30,"data":[{"value":"223118","type":1,"name":"Peter","language":3},
{"value":"223118","type":1,"name":"John","language":2},
{"value":"223118","type":2,"name":"Mike","language":1},
{"value":"223118","type":1,"name":"George","language":3}
....
]}
```

And I am using the standart select2 functionality for ajac loading:

```
$( selector ).select2({
        placeholder: "Search",
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        id: function(bond){return {id: bond._id};},
        ajax: {
            //url: $("#area-of-operating_0").attr('data-url'),
            url: 'myurl',
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 100,
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                     page_limit: 10, // page size
                    page: page // page number
                    //q: term
                };
            },

            results: function (data, page) {
                var more = (page * 10) < data.total;
                return {results: data.data, more: more}
            }
        },

        formatResult: selectFormatResult, // see example
        formatSelection: selectFormatSelection
})
```

The problem is that the json can be with 1000 elements. I want to make infinite scroll with 10 elements

Comment: Provide the code buddy

Comment: I guess you  can make a ajax call will some limit and based on the scroll you can call make the ajax call again for some more values

Comment: No, I dont have access to the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using just `select2` as the mentioned in the [demo](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#infinite)

> In order to enable the remote service must support some sort of a paging mechanism...

it is not possible to enable infinite scrolling if the server side does not support paging.

What you could do is to save the whole JSON in some JS-variable at the first request. Then you can sequentially get some more results out of the local variable when the user is scrolling down. Is this an option for you?